# Настройка Phpstorm восстановить

Tags: phpstorm

как вернуть левое дерево проекта и слева код

сейчас вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а нужно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте Ctrl+Shift+F12

Или восстановить вид по умолчанию - Shift+F12

И потом посмотрите, чтоб у Вас было галочками нужное отмечено, как на картинке, например:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, и еще - если у вас это получилось перейти в Presentation Mode (см внизу картинки) , то у вас там будет надпись Exit Presentation Mode - поднимите мышь в самый вверх - появится верхнее меню, и во View нажмите на Exit.

А потом Ctrl+Shift+F12

Или - если Вы спрятали активное окно, то:  View -> Tool Windows Bars -> кликаем, появляется галочка и слева будут вертикальные узкие закладки - кликаем по "Project"